# Qt C++ Integration tests (webcam, db)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, testing, webcam

I am developing an app in Qt, which uses webcam and then saves some summary data into the database. I am using Qt except 3rd party library which is used to capture images from webcam and generate needed data.

Question is how can I implement integration tests with QTest?

I mean basically, to be sure, that everything works I need to:

1. Simulate webcam somehow (pass some video or list of images) so that I can test whether gathered data is correct
2. Simulate db or create some mock to the Qt db access classes so that I can verify that proper rows are inserted or maybe use some memory db for the test?
3. Change system clock to simulate timer events - some of the actions in the app are performed after specific amount of time elapsed - how can I simulate that in the tests?

Comment: How is this going to be integration tests if you are going to simulate everything?

Comment: Integration I meant in sense, that I am simulating webcam, or at least what the camera see, but I am testing how my application integrates with it. The same with the db. But maybe I should call it unit tests anyway.

Comment: Quoting Qt doc: "Qt Test provides classes for __unit testing__ Qt applications and libraries." So if you really want to do integration testing it is not the right tool.

Comment: OK, so what are my other options? It can be other framework.

Answer (score 0):

So answering my own question:
I should use some mocking library like google mock. This way I can mock my class for gathering images from camera and call callbacks with captured images. I can do the same thing for db access and just verify, that proper inserts were generated.

Then it comes another question - how can I provide mocks to my application instead of real classes when executing a test?
Should I make an interface for them and then provide as constructor arguments to the QWindow?